# "write" not working on ko.computed when adding dynamically into observable array in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wV6GM/).

I want to add `ko.computed`s to a `ko.observableArray` dynamically:

```
self.items.push(ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return items[i];
    },
    write: function (value) {
        //some write action
        alert(value);
    }
}));
```

I need to manage the `write` function from the `ko.computed` into the array.
With this code, read works great, but **knockout** is not calling the `write` function, so `alert` is not being called.

Am I missing something? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What are you trying achieve?

Comment: Im trying to create an array of computed, and manage the `write` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it creating another **ViewModel**:

```
function item(value) {
    var self = this;

    self.value = ko.observable(value);
    self.computed = ko.computed({
        read: self.value,
        write: function (value) {
            alert(value);
            self.value(value);
        }
    });
}

function header(items) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        self.items.push(new item(items[i]));
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: computed" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

And [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nescalante/wV6GM/2/) working.